# Why there exists an element $ y\in G\setminus‎ L $ such that $ K/L_{G} = (\langle y \rangle L_{G})/L_{G} $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is finite supersoluble group. Then $ G $ has a chief series. Let $ L $ be a subgroup of $ G $ and $ K/L_{G} $ a chief factor of $ G $ where $ L_{G} $ is the core of $ L $ in $ G $. Since $ G $ is supersoluble, $ K/L_{G} $ is a cyclic group with prime order. Clearly, $ K $ is not contained in $ L $. Why there exists an element $ y\in G\setminus‎ L $ such that $ K/L_{G} = (\langle y \rangle L_{G})/L_{G} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $G$ is supersoluble, its chief factor is $1$ dimensional. So $|G|=|L_G||K/L_G|$. Since $|K/L_G|=p$, $K/L_G$ is generated by $yL_G$, $y\in G, y\notin L$, for otherwise $K/L_G=L_G$.

Comment: What is mean of dimensional?

Comment: Normally there are many chief factors which form a vector with a dimension. Supersoluble means there is one chief factor. So its dimension is 1.

Comment: But $ K/L_{G} = L_{G} $ don't result $ K/L_{G} = (\langle y \rangle L_{G})/L_{G} $

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: $K/L_G$ cyclic implies $\exists y \in K$ with $\langle y \rangle L_G/L_G=K/L_G$. Then $y \in L \Rightarrow K \le L$ which is false, so $y \not\in L$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, good explanation. Also $K/L_G\ne L_G$ for $K/L_G$ is quotient group.